# Add new col to df with max value by group

Tags: r

I'm attempting to first find the max `value` by some grouping `id`, and then I need to create a column with this extracted value for that grouping ID.

something like:

```
df$maxdvalue <-aggregate(value ~ id, data = df, max)
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, maxvalue, value = list(id= 1:1763,  : 
>         replacement has 1763 rows, data has 74619

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and as you are new to R / stackoverflow here are several methods I wish I knew early on:

```
# Groupwise aggregation 
# (note: the aggregate function applied can be changed to whatever is required) 

  # 1st base R method using "ave" function, assigned as vector:

  df$maxmpg <- ave(df$mpg, df$car_brand, FUN = max)

  # 2nd base R method, transforming dataframe using  "ave" function, assigned as dataframe: 

  df <- transform(df, maxmpg = ave(mpg, car_brand, FUN = max))

  # 3rd method using with syntax in conjunction with "ave", assigned as vector:  

  df$maxmpg <- with(df, ave(mpg, car_brand, FUN = max))

  # 4th method using cbind in conjunction with "ave", assigned as dataframe:  

  df <- cbind(df, maxmpg = ave(df$mpg, df$car_brand, FUN = max))

  # 5th method using tapply, assigned as vector:  

  df$maxmpg <- tapply(df$mpg, df$car_brand, max)

  # 6th base R method using lapply with lambda function  
  # and row-binding the each list element back into a df (assigned as df): 

  df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$car_brand), 

                                function(x){

                                  x$maxmpg <- max(x$mpg)

                                  return(x)

                                }

                              )
                          )

  # 7th base R solution using aggregate and merge (assigned as df): 

  df <- merge(df, setNames(aggregate(mpg ~ car_brand, df, FUN = max),

                           c("car_brand", "max_mpg")), by = "car_brand", all.x = TRUE)


  # Using pacakges: 

  # Create a vector of the required packages: 

  necessary_packages <- c("dplyr", "data.table")

  # Create a vector containing the names of any packages requiring installation: 

  new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]

  # If the vector has more than 0 elements, install the new pacakges
  # (and it's/their) associated dependencies: 

  if(length(new_packages) > 0){

    install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)

  }

  # Initialise the packages in the session: 

  lapply(necessary_packages,

         require,

         character.only = TRUE)

  # 8th method using dplyr, assigned as vector:

  df <- 

    df %>% 

    group_by(car_brand) %>% 

    mutate(maxmpg = max(mpg)) %>%

    ungroup()

# 9th solution using data.table (set as vector): 

dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, maxmpg := max(mpg), by = car_brand]
```

Data Used:

```
df <- data.frame(car_type = row.names(mtcars),

                 car_brand = gsub(" .*", "", row.names(mtcars)),

                 mtcars, 

                 row.names = NULL)
```